# Iterating over a List and using the objects inside an anonymous function

Tags: c#, silverlight, lambda

I have a `List<string>` and I want to iterate over this collection and do something with each string on a button click. I have a small example here to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
//items is a System.Collections.Generic.List<string>
foreach (string s in items)
{
    Button b = new Button() { Content = s };
    b.Click += (obj, ev) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
    //add b to form, container, etc...
}
```

As you would expect the buttons are created appropriately with the correct content, however when I click any of the buttons, the text inside the `MessageBox` is always the last string in `items`. What am I missing with this? Why is it that all the `Click` functions for the buttons are passed the last item in the collection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `foreach` loop is changing `s`, which is used in the lambda. The lambda uses the current value of `s` at the point of execution, not declaring it (in techspeak: "closures close over variables, not values"). You'll have to make a local variable:

```
foreach (string s in items)
{
    string local = s;
    Button b = new Button() { Content = s };
    b.Click += (obj, ev) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(local);
    }
    //add b to form, container, etc...
}
```

Thus you have a reference to the instance of `s` at the point of decleration, not execution.

Eric Lippert has two fantastic articles about it: [part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx), [part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx).

Comment: Note Eric Lippert’s blog entries about this: **[Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)** and **[Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx)**

Comment: +1 Brilliant, that did the trick. Thanks for the links, great articles.